# How to change SQL Server sa password as part of ec2 userdata

Tags: amazon-ec2, sql-server, powershell

I'm provisioning some development EC2 instances running Windows Server, with SQL Server installed. I use a custom Amazon Machine Image with the configuration we need, but as part of the provisioning process, I run a userData script on each machine that sets some values specific to that user, including a random password for certain applications. Part of the script does this for SQL Server, following [this example](https://www.johnsansom.com/powershell-change-sql-server-login-password/):

```perl
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") | Out-Null
$srv = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" localhost
$user = $srv.Logins | where Name -eq "sa"
$user.ChangePassword("<injected by provisioning process>");
$user.PasswordPolicyEnforced = 1;
$user.Alter();
$user.Refresh();
```

The weird thing is that when I run this manually on the box after it's spun up, **it works**. However, when I have it as part of the user data, it doesn't appear to have any effect -- you can't authenticate to the database with the new password. I know for certain that the full user data script is running without error. Other components before and after this code block are working as expected. Furthermore, I can see the `DateLastModified` attribute of the sa user reflects when the script ran.

Why would this behave any differently running in the user data script vs. me doing it manually in powershell?

(Yes, I'm aware this is not good practice, so to speak. These machines are not used for production: they're spun up temporarily, firewalled, and only used to test specific workflows)

Answer (score 1):

Well, turns out this was not the right approach, possibly because my userData script was not being run as Administrator. Instead, I found this to be successful:

```perl
net stop mssqlserver
net start mssqlserver /m
SQLCMD -E -Q "ALTER LOGIN [sa] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]; USE [master]; ALTER LOGIN [sa] WITH PASSWORD=N'<injected by provisioning process>'"
net stop mssqlserver
net start mssqlserver
```